# How do I get Bridge to share IP with a client?

Tags: networking, iptables

Router ----[eth0 TAP eth1]---- Client (10.0.0.10)

As above, there is a Linux device named TAP.
This device acts as a bridge (br0) and passes through the packets of Clients.

In this configuration, in order to communicate with the Internet in TAP, a separate IP of 10.0.0.x must be assigned to br0 and communicated with its own mac.

However, I would like to duplicate the MAC and IP of the Client to br0 of the TAP, and share the IP so that the TAP can communicate with the Internet.

The idea is similar to Intel vPro sharing a NIC.

How can I implement this?
Is it possible with iptables without program implementation?

Comment: This is all very confusing. FIrst you say that TAP is a bridge type device. Then, you say there's br0, which is actually the bridge. So, something's wrong about your description. And, experience tells me, when the solution to something seems to be sharing addresses, the approach is wrong and there's an easier way. So, please tell us what TAP actually is! How did you create it, how does it relate to your `br0`.

Comment: br0 is bridging eth0 and eth1 in TAP.
If, for my purposes, br0 is not needed and only iptables can do it, br0 is not necessary.

Comment: Honestly, I just made the bridge as usual, I don't know what my next step should be.. It's just a "guess" that you might be able to use iptables.

Comment: "br0 is bridging eth0 and eth1 in TAP" what is "*bridging in TAP*"? I don't understand this combination of words!. "I just made the bridge as usual", you will need to tell us what "as usual" means, in explicit commands.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I read it like this: "TAP" is a Linux system (it's not a tuntap interface). As OP wrote "device" I assume it's physical rather than a virtual experiment (not that it matters much).

Comment: @A.B yeah, I had similar considerations, but then that raises so many other questions. Let's not speculate – this is all easy for OP to clarify :)

Comment: "TAP" is a word inspired by Tap, a device that intervenes and monitors the network.
"TAP" is just a Linux machine with two Ethernet ports.
Please ignore that I made a bridge. It doesn't seem like anything important.

Comment: Ok, it seems super important, actually. So, I'm even more confused. Anyway, unless you explicitly tell us what you did there, we can't even try to answer your question. Seeing this has gone for 22 hours now – I've voted to close as sadly lacking necessary detail.